Integrate venmo payment with paypal restful api
I've done integrate Paypal payment with its Restful API without smart button, but I didn't find the  way to integrate with Venmo payment.
Is there any way to integrate with Venmo on App? (React Native)
The way I've try to use is that set payment source with venmo, but the link I got from create order response is not available when I want to use it. It's alway return AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE.
Thanks for every reply from all of you.

I dont have an answer related to Venmo but I use Stripe for my payment needs and it includes several payment merchants like PayPal and CashApp on top of credit card and bank info.

There is no way to integrate Pay with Venmo without the JS SDK.
Perhaps you are looking for the standalone buttons feature to have it only render Venmo when eligible.
The JS SDK can also be used for PayPal payments from a react native app if you use a native popup bridge, of which there are android and ios versions.
